# Feedback with a query I wrote [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql, group-by, having

So, I have written a query to extract the average unemployment rate in a given period.I would appreciate a feedback on the query and how far can I go to optimize something like this (or if it is worth optimizing at all)

PS: The result of the query is correct.

I am more interested in the perspective of the community at large when it comes to doing something as basic as this. What pitfalls do you see and recommendations on how one can avoid them?

```
select extract(year from period) as year, avg(data) as yearly_unemp_rate 
from fred.unemployment_rate_stg 
group by 1 
having extract(year from period) >= '1980'
and extract(year from period) < '2015' 
order by year;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're making average data in the period between 1980 and 2015.

I would suggest using where instead of having -

```
WHERE extract(year from period) >= '1980' AND extract(year from period) < '2015'
```

Having, we use when the aggregation is taken place and you want a filter on the same.